# ngx-bootstrap model scrolls to top of document

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I'm using ngx-bootstrap modals in a project that displays enough on the page the content scrolls vertically. Whenever a modal is opened the document body scrolls to the top instead of leaving the position alone, which is the expected behavior.

I can manually set `overflow: auto` on the body in the dev console to resolve this behavior. That is, once set, opening modals no longer scrolls to the top of the document body. However, adding this css to my component did not apply to the body. Changing the bootstrap css files in the node_modules folder also did not work. Bootstrap continues to set `overflow: hidden` and my component css file does not apply `body { overflow: auto !important; }` though it does successfully apply the other defined styles.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No, though I may be looking at this again in the near future.

Comment: I solved it putting this in the style.css 

body {
  overflow: auto;
}

Also I had the html tag with that style too and I removed it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

did you import @ngx-bootstrap in .ts file you are gonna use?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';`